# Unity score on touch adding up incorrectly

Tags: unity

I'm currently working on a game where a user can click an object and this should increase their scored by 1. Unfortunately it seems to be increasing it by more than 1 sometimes and I can't figure out why. The code to increase the score is below:

```
            if (Input.GetButton ("Fire1")) {

        Vector3 clickedPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (Input.mousePosition);
        RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast (clickedPosition, -Vector2.up);

        if (hit && !this.touched && (hit.rigidbody && hit.rigidbody.Equals(this.rigidbody2D))) {
            this.touched = true;

            this.rigidbody2D.isKinematic = true; //reset
            this.rigidbody2D.isKinematic = false;
            Vector3 hitPoint = this.transform.InverseTransformPoint (hit.point);
            rigidbody2D.AddForceAtPosition(new Vector2(maxVel,topForce), new Vector2(hitPoint.x,hitPoint.y));
            if(!scored){
            score+=1;
            scored = true;
            }

        }
    }
    if (this.transform.position.y < this.previousYPosition) {
        this.touched = false;
        scored = false;
    }

    this.previousYPosition = this.transform.position.y;
      }
```

As you can see I've tried adding a number of booleans to try and ensure it only updates if certain conditions are met. What's weird is that sometimes it doesn't only add one and sometimes it adds more. I can only assume the update is being called multiple times, but then as far as I am aware it should fail my if conditions.

I've also tried moving this to the OnMouseDown method and moving the boolean checks into FixedUpdate() instead, and although this is slightly better, it still doesn't seem to be correct.

Any advice?

Comment: If people are going to leave negative votes, perhaps leave a comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Input.GetButton()` will return true for each frame that the "button" is down.

`Input.GetButtonDown()` or `Input.GetButtonUp()` will return true only on the frame that the button goes down or up respectively.

---

As an aside if your score is rising unpredictably it would require that your `touched` and `scored` flags are being reset.

1. If you have posted all of the code that handles these variables then that means that "`this.transform.position.y < this.previousYPosition`" is evaluating to `true` under some circumstances?!? Are you detecting a bounce, or the effects of some other code that is manipulating it's position? If the latter then maybe you could reset the flags in that other block of code rather than checking for its effects.
2. If there is other code manipulating these flags one approach that is guaranteed to provide insight is to change the variables to properties, then apply a breakpoint to the setter.  This will allow you to step though to the code that call calling the setter and examine the circumstances of that call.

Comment: Thanks for replying but I resolved this as per my comments on Karmington's post

Answer (score 0):

Most likely this.touched is getting set to false.

Solution, use MouseUp?

Additional advice: if you are not yet stepping through code while it's running, I recommend learning about breakpoints.

Comment: I'm familiar with breakpoints and had stepped through the code.The code above is the only code that resets the vars and it should only fire when the object is falling.MouseUp won't work as you could potentially "MouseUp" when you're not over the object due to the forces being added to it, as such it won't get fired. I've done a bit more testing as well and it appears that the issue was around my rayCast check in the update method. I've moved all this logic (other than the position check to reset) into the mouseDown event and it is now working as expected